# SQLAlchemy get() returns None

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Got strange behavior, when `.get()` returns None.

```
class Model(Base):
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id`
```

Some times (3-5 times in 30k runs)

`db.query(Model).with_for_update(of=Model, key_share=True).get(model_id)`

returns None.

Then, we added `filter_by(id=model_id).first()`, this query returns entity. Any ideas, may be we are loosing our entity in identity map?

- PostgreSQL 9.5
- SQLAlchemy 1.1.2

Comment: Can you try to print your queries in order to see what PostgreSQL request it does under it?

A wild guess will be adding `skip_locked=True` at your `with_for_update` but I am really not sure. Good luck finding a solution and please post it whenever you succeed.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example that produces the error?

Comment: @IljaEverilä sometimes you get it with a simple ```session.query(Model).get(id)```

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer It is supposed to return `None` when a row with the given primary key is not found or available in the context of the current transaction, isolation level, and locking (and it has not been loaded before in the current session).

Comment: @IljaEverilä that comment qualifies for an answer